# How does one interpret the expression $\lim_{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^{m}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a book about real analysis, where the author introduces following definition of limits:

> **Definition** (Limits of sequences). If a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to some real number $L$, we say that $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is convergent and its limit is L; we write
> $$L = \lim_{\color{red}n \rightarrow \infty}a_\color{red}n$$

But then I came across following expression $$\lim_{\color{green}{m+1} \rightarrow \infty} x^{\color{red}m}$$

Note that the variable underneath the $\lim$ and the exponent of $x$ are mismatched. Furthermore, the author seems to suggest that provided $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}x^{m}$ exists, it must be the case that

$$\lim_{m+1 \rightarrow \infty}x^{m} = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}x^{m}$$

**Questions**.

1. How does one interpret $\lim_{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^{m}$? Unfortunately, I don't see how the aforementioned definition of the limits allows us to freely change the variable underneath the $\lim$.
2. How does one rigorously justify the equality $\lim_{m+1 \rightarrow \infty}x^{m} = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}x^{m}$?

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Maybe it was a "shift in index", or a typo.

Comment: $$m\to \infty \iff m+1 \to \infty$$

Comment: @PrimeMover Real Analysis 1 by Terence Tao (He mentioned the expression $\lim_{m+1}x^{m}$ in the example 1.2.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that

$$\lim_{m+1\to\infty}x^m=\lim_{m+1\to\infty}x^{(m+1)-1}$$

and the limit is formally equivalent to

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}x^{m-1}.$$

(In a second step, you can show that $\lim_{m\to\infty}x^{m-1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}x^m$.)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can interpret $$\lim_{m + 1 \to \infty}a_m = L$$ to mean the following: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $$|a_m - L| < \epsilon$$ for all $m$ satisfying $m + 1 \ge N$. (Use $>$ instead of $\ge$ if your $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limit uses that.)
   **Exercise:** Assuming you know what the limit of a real function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ means, try figuring out what $$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)$$ would mean.
2. With the above definition, try to work this out yourself. Given an $N$ which works for $\lim_{m \to \infty}a_m$, can you come up with an $N$ which works for $\lim_{m + 1 \to \infty}a_m$? And vice-versa?